# MySQL Replace is not working

Tags: mysql, replace

I try to use mysql replace with following table.

```
CREATE TABLE price (
   id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   ski_chalet_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
   month DATE NOT NULL, 
   d_1 DOUBLE(18, 2), 
   d_2 DOUBLE(18, 2), 
   d_3 DOUBLE(18, 2), 
   d_4 DOUBLE(18, 2), 
   d_5 DOUBLE(18, 2), 
   created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, 
   updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, 
   UNIQUE INDEX fk_ski_chalet_price_ski_chalet_idx (ski_chalet_id, month), 
   INDEX ski_chalet_id_idx (ski_chalet_id), 
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I want add a row if row is not exist and update if row is exist. So i used mysql REPLACE to do that.

```
REPLACE INTO  `price` SET `ski_chalet_id` = 43 and `month` = '2013-04-01' and `d_1` = 23
```

This query is successful. but add all value as 00 and 0000-00-00 or null.

But insert query is working.

```
INSERT INTO `price` (`ski_chalet_id`,`month`,`d_1`) VALUES ('34', '2013-04-01', '46');
```

I cant find whats the issue. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use "," instead on "and" in replace query ........

REPLACE INTO  `price` SET `ski_chalet_id` = 43 , `month` = '2013-04-01' , `d_1` = 23

**NOTE** : REPLACE function will work want you want you don't have to look for   other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `SET` with `REPLACE`. The syntax for `REPLACE` is the same as for `INSERT`:

```
REPLACE INTO `price` (`ski_chalet_id`,`month`,`d_1`) VALUES ('43', '2013-04-01', '23');
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify multiple columns with `SET` in `REPLACE` (and `UPDATE` / `INSERT`), you must separate them with commas.  Your query amounts to:

```
SET `ski_chalet_id` = (some boolean expression)
```

Rewrite as

```
SET `ski_chalet_id` = 43, `month` = '2013-04-01', `d_1` = 23
```